# How to generate auto registration no before adding an employee in employee table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a application that keep the record of employees, i wish to do some thing like that when a user goes to register a new employee, an employee registration number should be automatically generated in SQL, i.e registration number for first employee should be ISO-2016-01 and for second employee it should be ISO-2016-02 and so on.

Comment: why not just use an identity column that increments for you? if required, you could then reformat it to add the 'ISO-XXX' prefix when it's displayed to users?

Comment: Following on from @Tanner, I assume for each year the registration number changes i.e. in 2017 it'll be ISO-2017-NN? Also, should you ever reach employee counts beyond 99, does this registration number continue like so: ISO-2016-100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id like **ISO-2016-01** can not be generated automatically by SQL Server. You will have to write a function which will generate this id for you every time before you add any new row into the table. The function will -
1. Check for the current year
2. Last id generated for current year (you may want to keep a track of ids for a given year)
3. Generate the next id using the above data.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without creating an extra field if the RegistrationNumber is always in the same format (ISO-2016-xxx)

you can get your last number like this :

```
select top 1 substring(r.RegistrationNumber, 10, len(r.RegistrationNumber)) 
from   Registrations r
where  substring (r.RegistrationNumber, 5, 4) = '2016'
order by substring(r.RegistrationNumber, 10, len(r.RegistrationNumber)) desc
```

assuming that it will always be ISO-2016- (= 9 characters)

a complete sql that you can use for the function would be something like this :

```
declare @year varchar(4) = convert(varchar, datepart(year, getdate()))
declare @prefix varchar(9) = 'ISO-' + @year + '-'
declare @number int
declare @result varchar(20)

select top 1 
       @number = substring(r.RegistrationNumber, 10, len(r.RegistrationNumber)) 
from   Registrations r
where  substring (r.RegistrationNumber, 5, 4) = @year
order by substring(r.RegistrationNumber, 10, len(r.RegistrationNumber)) desc

set @number = @number + 1
set @result = @prefix + convert(varchar, @number)

select @result
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employes 
    ADD RegistrationNumber AS CONCAT('ISO-', DATEPART(year, DateReg), '-', Id);
```

where `DateReg` - name of column with user registration datetime, `Id` - identity column